# is_callable doesn't work on server

Tags: php, symfony

after uploading my project to server I constantly get this error:

> InvalidArgumentException in AccessDecisionManager.php line 52: The
>   strategy "affirmative" is not supported.

I checked AccessDecisionManager and found this code:

```
public function __construct(array $voters, $strategy = self::STRATEGY_AFFIRMATIVE, $allowIfAllAbstainDecisions = false, $allowIfEqualGrantedDeniedDecisions = true)
{
    ....

    $strategyMethod = 'decide'.ucfirst($strategy);
    if (!is_callable(array($this, $strategyMethod))) {
        throw new \InvalidArgumentException(sprintf('The strategy "%s" is not supported.', $strategy));
    }

    ....
}
```

I checked with var_dump that `$strategyMethod` = `'decideAffirmative'`

But `is_callable` returns false even if method is present!

```
private function decideAffirmative(TokenInterface $token, array $attributes, $object = null)
{
    ....
}
```

In local server it turns perfectly. On remote I get false. [PHPInfo of server](https://phpinfo.olympe.in)

Thanks